# Rails won't upload css images

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, asset-pipeline

I have read other posts but none solved my problem. The image has been successfully uploaded to Amazon S3. I've removed

```
config.action_dispatch.x_sendfile_header = "X-Sendfile"
```

In my css file if I use

```
background-image: url('background.jpg');
```

The image will show in development mode but not in production.

If I use

```
background-image: url(<%= asset_path 'background.jpg' %>)
```

The image won't show either in development mode or in production. I'm using rails 3.2.9 Thanks!

Comment: Try : `background-image: url(<%= asset_path %>/'background.jpg')` in case you have placed your image in an asset directory and your file is prefixed with `.erb`. Normally `url(background.jpg)` is enough.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You likely need to configure your app to set it's asset host: `config.action_controller.asset_host`. This guide will probably help you: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/cdn-asset-host-rails31